# How to export DokuWiki to Latex or MarkUp Language and pdf

Tags: pdf, export, markup, pandoc, dokuwiki

We are using dokuwiki for product documentation and I am all other than happy with the available export to pdf function.
What alternatives are there?
My special interest is to get away from dokuwiki versioning and have something more git compatible (to version it along side the code) that can be easily exported to dokuwiki AND pdf in the end (high quality PDF with index and so on preferably).

I just came accross pandoc, but it seems to take dokuwiki as an output but not to import from dokuwiki (see screenshot below).

[image]

Did you make any good experiences with versioned documentation and the mentioned export functionality?

Comment: First of all, how is this related to programming? And secondly: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

try latexit dokuwiki plugin!
https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:latexit
pandoc can export Latex to all other formats